# m_videoOverlayTextureY pixels are not valid, but the texture render correctly with GUI.DrawTexture

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm trying to get the YUV image from the camera but when I try to read the pixels in the `YUVTexure` provided by `GetVideoOverlayTextureYUV()` all the pixels are set to '205'. The weird thing is I can draw the the 'Y' texture with`GUI.DrawTexture(someRect, _texture.m_videoOverlayTextureY);` and I can see the image is there, I just can't read it with `getPixels()`.

I'm also using the `Tango AR Camera` prefab in the project so `m_useExperimentalVideoOverlay` is set to true. We tried to use the non experimental API but then the AR Camera prefab stopped working.

As anyone been able to acces the image data in Unity using `IExperimentalTangoVideoOverlay`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texture from `GetVideoOverlayTextureYUV` is different than the regular Unity Texture2D. In the Tango Unity SDK, it creates a Texture2D object on the Unity level and passes the textureID to native C++ API to filled out. So the texture pixel value is not stored to Unity, instead, it gets copied to GPU memory directly from native code, and Unity texture only have the textureID of it. That's why it can be rendered out, but can not be read.

To get the actual byte buffer from color camera, you should used the [ITangoVideoOverlay interface](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/unity/reference/interface/i-tango-video-overlay). The callback returns a YUV buffer, the conversion function to RGB is same as the one in the [YUV2RGB.shader](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoPrefabs/Shaders/YUV2RGB.shader#L132)

Comment: Yes we tried doing that, but since the `AR Camera` prefab already uses the ITangoExperimentalTangoVideoOverlay we were not able to use the two interfaces at the same time, probably for good reason.

Comment: Since I need to send the buffer to a native plugin anyway, I tried to connect to the frame callback directly in the native plugin with `TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable` and it seems to be working right now.

Comment: Native `TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable` is the one we used to get the byte buffers too, but I think the unity sdk is kind of messy on that part at the moment, I've put in a clean up change for next release, so it should be much more clean after the next release..